# Builds not being cached with sveltejs and vite

Tags: vite, svelte

I have a svelte project (not sveltekit) that is being built/bundled by vite.

The problem I am having is that the build times are growing unwieldly.
Most of the time this project is being built without any changes to it (part of a bigger project), but it still builds for ~10 seconds, which makes me think that it is not doing any caching at all.

So my question is: is it possible to enable a build cache for vite?

And as a side thing:
if I am building with the watch flag, each save triggers a full rebuild. Is it possible to only partially rebuild the code to speed things up?

my config currently looks like this

```
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "$lib": __dirname + "/src/svelte/lib",
      "$logo": __dirname + "/src/LogoTool",
    }
  },
  plugins: [svelte(), i18n()],
  build: {
    cssMinify: 'lightningcss',
    rollupOptions: {
      cache: true,
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }
    },
    lib: {
      entry: "./src/svelte/main.ts",
      formats: ["umd"],
      name: "svelte"
    },
    minify: 'terser',
    terserOptions: {
      compress: true,
      mangle: true,
      keep_classnames: false,
      ie8: false
    },
  },
  publicDir: "assets",
  server: {
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not meant to do a regular build on change, use the dev server instead ([`vite dev`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/cli.html#dev-server)).

It compiles only the necessary files and does not do any costly post-processing (minification, de-duping, etc.). Changed files are updated in place via hot module replacement (no page reload required unless state is out of sync).

See the [backend integration](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html#backend-integration) docs, if the rest of your application/page needs to be served separately.

Comment: To a degree I agree with you. I am well aware that this isn't what you "should" do, but in the situation I am in I am forced to create new distributions to be hosted by a server that is not vite. So running `vite dev` is fine(/fantastic) but does not output a new bundle, and is thus unusable for me

Comment: That is what the backend integration is for. You do not need to serve everything from the same server, so these parts of the front-end code can come from Vite's dev server.